# Global object in phtml or block - how does it work and how can i create one?

Tags: blocks, phtml

In the following file, I found this code:

```
<?php echo $countries->toHtmlOptions($data->getCountryId()) ?>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/address.phtml

$countries has not been instantiated in this phtml file and it kinds of looks like a global object. Typically, we just use $this-> to access methods and some other info in phtml files. I was also trying to find the related block for this global object($countries) and could not find it so easily. They also have few more variables in this template file.

How did they do it? May be, I can do something similar when it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 1.9 I don't find any usage of this template anymore, but it's possible to create variables for templates with `assign()`:

```
$block->assign('countries', $countries);
```

or in layout XML

```
<action method="assign"><var>countries</var><value>A,B,C</value></action>
```

---

However this method is seldomly used and I would not consider it good practice. The preferred method is to add and retrieve data to the block with magic setters and getters:

```
$block->setCountries($countries);
```

and in the template:

```
$this->getCountries()
```